# Pull data from dynamic measurement name by uisng InfluxQL query

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

In my application I am showing metrics to `grafana` from `influxdb`. I have dynamic name in `influxdb db`. e.g. `customer_info_{customerId}`.
My question is in `influxQL` query how can I use dynamic measurement name so I can display metrics from it.

Comment: You are using discouraged schema design https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/#avoid-encoding-data-in-measurement-names

Comment: Hi Jan Garaj, thank you for your comment. I am new to `grafana` and `InfluxQL`. I will change the query and will add `tags`. Can you please let me know if I add `Query variables` to `grafana`, then how `inluxql` query will change or how to build dashboard based on selected variable. If you can provide me any documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the structure, so `customerid` will be a tag in the `measurement`.

Then create Grafana dashboard variable `customerid` from InfluxDB query:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "customerid"
```

And use it as `$customerid` in the InfluxDB Grafana panel queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "measurement" 
WHERE 
  "customerid" = $customerid 
  AND $timeFilter
```

Doc is your friend: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/influxdb/influxdb-templates/